# Identificar que cambios hizo laravel con make:auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, autenticación

Me gustaría saber si existe algún comando o algo que me pueda indicar que cambios en que documentos a echo "`php artisan make:auth`" en mi carpeta de proyecto y que documentos a creado
Por fin me a quedado mi login personalizado con mailing y sesión de usuario y me gustaría poder entender que puedo modificar y que estoy afectando antes de hacer mayores cambios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el archivo Illuminate/Auth/Console/AuthMakeCommand.php encuentras todo lo que hace dicho comando:

```
/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    $this->createDirectories();

    $this->exportViews();

    if (! $this->option('views')) {
        file_put_contents(
            app_path('Http/Controllers/HomeController.php'),
            $this->compileControllerStub()
        );

        file_put_contents(
            base_path('routes/web.php'),
            file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/stubs/make/routes.stub'),
            FILE_APPEND
        );
    }

    $this->info('Authentication scaffolding generated successfully.');
}
```

Un poco resumido, lo que hace es:

1. Verificar que existen y en caso contrario, crear los directorios: views/layouts y views/auth/passwords.
2. Exportar las vistas desde sus respectivas plantillas (.stub) a resources.
3. (Opcional) Generar el controlador HomeController.php con el middleware de autenticación en el constructor, y agregar al final del archivo de rutas web.php lo relacionado con las rutas de autenticación (Login, registro, password olvidado, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes revisar los cambios en la carpeta de controladores **Auth/** así como también en las migraciones y modelos, en donde crea la tabla con sus columnas y atributos.

Te adjunto la documentación para consulta:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication